# bbm.sty not found, unknown option 'ngerman'

Tags: babel, german

there is a piece of my header.tex:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,toc=bibliography,chapterprefix,parskip=true}{scrreprt}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------

%%% Laden elementarer Pakete
%
% Deutsche Schriftpakete
             % alternativ: 'utf8' oder 'latin9' statt ansinew


\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% Mathematische Pakete
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, bm, bbm}         % Formelsetzung und      mathematischen Symbole
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}     % Theorem-Umgebungen,      alternativ: 'amsthm'
%
% Grafik-Pakete einbinden
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag}                % Basis-Pakete zum Laden von      Bildern (jpg?)
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
```

But I get errors

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `ngerman'. Either you misspelled it
! Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option.
header.tex line 14! LaTeX Error: File `bbm.sty' not found.
```

But packages texlive-babel-german, texlive-bbm, texlive-bbm-macros, texlive-collection-extras are installed. Replacing ngerman by german or ngermanb or germanb has no effect. And in the line 15 of header.tex I have nothing about bbm. Thanks in advance!

[the whole project as a zip-file](http://yadi.sk/d/HinRH8WsLZNtP)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am able to compile this just fine on my machine, when I add some actual content. (And after replacing the `}` with a `]`, which I assume is a typo.) Please provide a *complete* [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the behavior you are getting so we can help you out.

Comment: Note that you are **much** more likely to get help if you post an MWE as @Adam suggested than if you post a link to a zip file of your entire project. Very few people will be willing to download a whole archive, unpack it and pick through it just to help you. There are other questions... ;)

Comment: I added a zip-file because of the project structure. there are a few chapter files, one main file and one header file. there is no way to post them separately in accordance with the project structure.